# Test a page using v-calendar with Jest, Testing Library and Vue.js/Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, react-testing-library, vcalendar

I'm trying to test a page that uses [v-calendar](https://vcalendar.io/) and I'm missing some nested elements that I can't query because there just not in the rendered DOM (I get:    `TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element...`). They're also not displayed when I try to call `debug()`, I only get some HTML comments instead. Why is that happening exactly and is there a way to specify the render depth (I supposed that's why it's not showing)?

```html
<div
  class="vc-popover-content-wrapper"
  data-v-39b30300=""
>
  <!---->
</div>
```

*Output from debug where I'd like to see the content of that div*